# How to call a Stored Procedures in cakephp?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a Stored Procedure from my cakephp controller.Now what i'm doing is this
`$this->Twitter->query('call update_twitter(' . $userid . ',\'' . $twittername . '\');');`

is there any better method than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of CakePHP 1.3, that's the only way to call a stored procedure.  There is a feature request that's listed as "Future" milestone, but that's it. See [Ticket #734](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/734-cakephps-model-class-doesnt-support-calling-stored-procedures)